# How to fetch data from a class with two list inside?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, class

I have a class with 2 list inside and don't know how to fetch through all 2 list to get all data,
thank you for reading my question.

my MODEL

```
namespace BaoCao.Models
{
    public class ProductPage
    {
        public List<PRODUCT> listproduct { get; set; }
        public List<TYPE_PRODUCTS> listtype_product { get; set; }

        public static ProductPage getAll()
        {
            DB db = new DB();
            ProductPage a = new ProductPage();
            a.listproduct = db.PRODUCTS.ToList();
            a.listtype_product = db.TYPE_PRODUCTS.ToList();
            return a;
        }
        ProductPage()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

MY VIEW

```
namespace BaoCao.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Product
        public ActionResult Product()
        {
            var dssp = ProductPage.getAll();
            return View(dssp);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you say `MY VIEW`, but that's not a view; that's a controller. Generally, you should create a `viewmodel` that has the structure you desire (the 2 lists), and then return *that* via your controller. What you're returning through your view (`dssp`) is the full model. It actually does have the lists that you want in there, but you need to reference them appropriately in your view, which we can't see.

Comment: yes, thank you that is exactly how can i resolved my problem.

Comment: As an aside, in C# public members should use `PascalCase` without any underscores ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)). Further, collections should be plural. So your members should be something like `Products`, `TypeProducts`, `GetAll()`.

Comment: Also, long term, you'll find that having a static factory method to retrieve data from your database isn't a very flexible pattern, nor is it ideal for testing. Preferably, your view model or data transfer object will simply contain properties. But even if it's an entity, you're likely better suited having a repository class that focuses exclusively on retrieving data from the database, instead of integrating that logic with your entity class itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product.cshtml

```
@model BaoCao.Models.ProductPage
@foreach (var product in Model.listproduct) {
...
}
```

The details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller#strongly-typed-models-and-the--keyword).